# Generate isolated labels from segmented image

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, mask

Here is the idea. 
After image segmentation, i would like to save/ isolate each label (different size) on a smaller image. And create my dataset for machine learning. I can easaly code this on python, but i'm sure there already is function for this.

If you have any idea for function / libraries.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at nipy/nilabels . It is not clear what you are looking for exactly, but maybe some of the components you need are already implemented here. CONFLICT of INTEREST NOTICE: yes, I am one of the nilabels developers.

Comment: To be more specific, i'm working on 2D Black&White image of blood cells and i want to isolated each cell saved on a smaller image. I'll have a image dataset (same size even if blodd cell size is different) of isolated cell to train a model.